# Why we extends AbstractTabelModel when set values into JTabel?

Tags: java, swing, oop

Im developing a app for ordeing system and i have to set data into JTabels. 
And this code is successfully working.I wanted to know what the importance of and whats happen in this class?
Why we need to import AbstractTabelModel.class?

OrderTabelModel Class:-

```
  public class OrderTableModel extends AbstractTableModel{
    protected static final String[] COLUMN_NAMES={"Item","Qty","Amount"};
       private List<Order> rows;

    public OrderTableModel(List<Order> rows){
        this.rows = new ArrayList<>(rows);
    }



    @Override
        public int getRowCount() {
            return rows.size();
        }

        @Override
        public int getColumnCount() {
            return COLUMN_NAMES.length;
        }

         @Override
        public String getColumnName(int column) {
            return COLUMN_NAMES[column];
        }
        @Override
       public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
            Object value = null;
            Order row = rows.get(rowIndex);
            switch (columnIndex) {
                case 0:
                    value = row.getItem();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    value = row.getQty();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    value = row.getAmount();
                    break;
            }
            return value;
        }



    }
```

this is other class

```
private void tblOrderListMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
      int raw = tblOrderList.getSelectedRow();
      Order or;
      String item;
      Double qty,amount,total;

      ArrayList<Order> arrOrder = new ArrayList<Order>();

      String selectedRaw = tblOrderList.getModel().getValueAt(raw, 0).toString();
      System.out.println("order id : "+selectedRaw);
      String sql = "select item,qty,amount from orderdetails where orderid='"+selectedRaw+"'";
      con = new DBconnector().connect();
        try {
            Statement   ps =con.createStatement();
            ResultSet rs2 = ps.executeQuery(sql);
           while(rs2.next()){
                or = new Order();
                or.setItem(rs2.getString("item"));
                System.out.println("Item :" +rs2.getString("item"));
                or.setQty(rs2.getDouble("qty"));
                or.setAmount(rs2.getDouble("amount"));

                arrOrder.add(or);
            }
            rs2.close();
            ps.close();
            OrderTableModel tblModel = new OrderTableModel(arrOrder);          
            tblOrderItems.setModel(tblModel);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Can some one explain me the process of this please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not always mandatory to extend the `AbstractTableModel`. You can simply extend the `DefaultTableModel` and only override the `getValueAt()` method if you have to.

But most of the time for simple usages it is not even needed to override the `getValueAt()` method either.

By using the DefaultTableModel, you have a limitation for the converting you data (imported from DB) to an `object[][]` or `Vector` types which may be a little boring.

But you asked what is the importance of using `AbstractTabelModel`?

In this case I can say when `JTable` is started to being rendered, it needs to determine the number of rows and number of the columns and also it needs to know which data should be renedered in each cell and so on. Based on this, `JTable` ask for this Information from the underlying `TableModel`. So it is needed for your TableModel(any child or implementation of TableModel) to have those methods which are used by `JTable` to retrieve the needed information.

Hope this would be helpful.

Good Luck.